# Inconsistent Object State Error In Entity Framework When Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following code to simulate an owner selling his dog to someone else and the dog getting a new name:

```
public void ChangeOwner(int oldOwnerID, int newOwnerID, int dogID, string newDogName)
{
    var oldOwner = _objectContext.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == oldOwnerID);
    oldOwner.DogID = null;

    var newOwner = _objectContext.People.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == newOwnerID);
    newOwner.DogID = dogID;

    var dog = _objectContext.Dogs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == dogID);
    dog.Name = newDogName;

    _objectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This code will throw the following error:

Additional information: The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

Why is this error occuring and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you look at your table definition /creation and look to see if you added or assigned a primary key and set (Is Identity) property to yes

if the you get an error after that ...remove the entity and recreate it and that should solve the problem but this sounds like a primary Key Issue..

Comment: I had all my primary keys set to identities in my EDMX file, so I removed the problem entity and added it back and now it's working. Thanks for your help! This is the weirdest way to get it working!

Comment: I know but the good thing is that I gave you a really quick fix and I am more than happy that it actually worked for you.. I spent 2 hours trying to get another OP do get something working when he fought me on my suggestion just to go back and do what I asked and it worked..LOL glad I could help out

Answer (score 1):

I'd gotten this problem myself, and the above answer is exactly right in saying that it's a PRIMARY KEY issue, but being new to ASP.NET MVC, I didn't know exactly how to implement the solution.

So, for those ASP.NET MVC n00bs like myself who would like to see some code and what worked for me:

My issue was that the KEY in my MODEL didn't match the KEY in the SQL TABLE.

Eg. My PRIMARY KEY is on 'Event_Question_ID' in my table.  But in my MODEL it was on a different field, EventID.

All I had to do was move the KEY to the correct field in my MODEL

Model:

```
[Key]   
public int Event_Question_ID { get; set; }
```

Note: `[Key]` requires `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`

I hope this helps someone out there!